# Rotation issue in ZStack - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, rotation, zstack

Here , I'm trying to apply same rotation in both these elements.But these object or elements are doing un wanted behaviour, they are not rotating as same as others . So I want to rotate them all as same , So that no the blue card gets behind the image.
I mean I want them all to be in same rotation.

[image]

Here my code -

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing : 10){
        
        
        ZStack {
            ZStack (alignment : .bottom){
                ZStack(alignment : .bottom){
                    
                    Image("cat")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: length, height: length)
                                
                    
                    Text("<>")
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.orange)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                               
                }
                .frame(width: length, height: length)
                .background(.blue)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(-totalRotation.width)))
                
                Text("<>")
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                           
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            totalRotation.width = value.translation.width + currentRotation.width
                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            currentRotation = totalRotation
                                            mainAngle = totalRotation
                                        }
                                )
                
                
                Text("\(mainAngle.width) --- \(totalRotation.width)")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            .frame(width: length, height: length)
            .background(.blue)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(-mainAngle.width)))
        }
        .frame(width: length, height: length)
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(-mainAngle.width)))
        }
    .frame(width: length, height: length)

   
    


        
        Text("\(angle)")
        
        
        
        
        }
 }[![Here the image to get much information][1]][1]
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code - the only Image here is "cat" (is that the name of the person?) Then, the image itself has a blue background, along with the outer ZStack (which includes **<>**, which is not shown in the preview - is that supposed to be **...**??) which also has a blue background. Try making things different colors so they're easy to track - make one red and one green, for example, so it's easy to see when one moves. The picture you provided does not seem to match the code you provided.

Comment: you have overall three `rotationEffect` in your code, I would guess the one on the outermost `ZStack` would be enough, because it will effect everything inside of it.

Comment: thank you @ChrisR , I got it . Thanks a lot